# curl options for libcurl method in download.file

Tags: r, curl, libcurl

Is it possible to pass curl options when using `base::download.file` in R with `method = "libcurl"`?

I need to pass those curl options in my environment:

- CURLOPT_PROXY (this is optional as the value for this is taken from the environment variables)
- CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME
- CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH
- CURLOPT_USERAGENT

For example for a cmd it would be:

```
--proxy-negotiate --proxy-user ::: --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.3.2 httr/1.4.4"
```

I know there is `RCurl::getURL` and `curl::curl_download` where I can pass those curl options. I am bit surprised it is not possible with `base::download.file`.